# VCL Styles for Inno Setup having problems skinning some downloader page elements

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript, vcl-styles, inno-download-plugin, inno-tools-downloader

I used VCL Styles for Inno Setup in an attempt to try to skin my installer and ran into a small issue I hope someone might be able to help with.

I need to apologize in advance. I have been muddling through these for a while, taking clips of things here and there to get it to work in my installer the way I wanted, and am by no means a guru when it comes to programming. In fact, it gives me migraines, but I have to get it done somehow. In short, my coding isn't expert by any means, but I try to get things done.

I have been using an installer I made sometime in 2008. Just recently I wanted to add to it, make it do things more automatically, have less and more insightful prompts, and look better.

I added InnoTools Downloader by Sherlock Software when i first made it, and have used that ever since with really no problems.

I just added VCL Styles, and there is an element inside InnoTools Downloader that I have absolutely no idea how to skin along with the rest of the installer. Everything else is looking great, but the small box inside the download page was gray.

[image]

So, I tried Inno Download Plugin by Mitrich Software. Hey, the gray box was gone, but shucks.. The error window text is light gray on white background and unreadable.

[image]

I did more searching and found [How to apply VCL styles to DLL-based forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805807/how-to-apply-vcl-styles-to-dll-based-forms-in-inno-setup). When I tried to load InnoTools Downloader by Sherlock Software using:

```
procedure DllLoadStyle(const StyleFilename: WideString);
  external 'DllLoadStyle@files:itdownload.dll stdcall';
```

I just got en error: Unknown Type 'WideString'

I am using the ANSI version of Inno Setup because when I originally tried the Unicode version years and years ago, it messed up the InnoTools downloader, and I have been using ANSI ever since.

I tried changing WideString to just String, to match the formatting VCL already was using:

```
procedure LoadVCLStyle(VClStyleFile: String);
  external 'LoadVCLStyleA@files:VclStylesInno.dll stdcall';
```

But, that unfortunately gave me an error when running the installer:

```
Runtime Error (at -1:0):
Cannot Import dll:C:\...\Temp\is-XXXXX.tmp\itdownloaded.dll
```

1) I'm wondering if I'm kind of out of luck with wanting this part skinned because of both downloaders using an external .dll?
2) Is there possibly a way to direct VCL to skin that element on the page?
3) Can either of the .dll files be loaded in similar fashion to the linked page (and original VCL .dll file)?
4) Would using the Unicode version of Inno Setup give me any additional means of resolving this (As long as I don't have to rewrite a whole bunch of code on my original installers)?

I am very sorry, I'm really not understanding anything to do with new pages very well at this time. Most of what I did with my installers use MsgBox to avoid having to deal with them in situations where there are new updates and other such notifications that might require user input.

I put together a sample code taken from one of my installers if it is helpful, and can post that if requested. It is probably a big mess for any real programmer to even look at and don't want to give everyone a headache (or whiplash shaking their head in disgust), but just let me know if it would be helpful or if what I already put here is sufficient to explain what I'm running into.

If I manage to get 10 reputation, I can also post example images as well if helpful.

I can always live with it, but would really like to get that fixed and I apologize in advance if anything is unclear, as this is my first question.

Thanks in advance for any help and insight.

VCL Styles for Inno Setup 1.2.2.1 / Inno Setup 5.5.5a installed from ispack-5.5.5.exe / InnoTools Downloader 0.3.5 / Inno Download Plugin 1.4.0.

Edit: Added images (thanks for the points to do so). Ignore the error about download failed, I did that so it would stop and popup a box to capture the skinning of the window and popup.

Comment: The `itdownload.dll` library does not contain a function `DllLoadStyle`. What is that `DllLoadStyle` function ? Where does it come from ? It's not from [`ITD`](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=50), nor from [`VCL styles`](https://code.google.com/p/vcl-styles-plugins/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FInnoSetup%20plugin) for Inno Setup. Then to the skinning problem, the ITD plugin uses its own UI component classes for whose are missing VCL style hooks (see the [`liteui.pas`](https://github.com/wilbit/itdownload/blob/master/Source/liteui.pas) unit).

Comment: @TLama It sounds like OP stumbled on some code I probably wrote customized in this library, sounds very familiar... Anyway, I'm pretty sure the problem is that you're not using the Unicode version of Inno Setup, as I was when I wrote that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805807/how-to-apply-vcl-styles-to-dll-based-forms-in-inno-setup/21815937#21815937

Comment: @TLama I got it from and example JerryDodge posted (linked in my post and his comment) about someone's personal DLL, but I figured I would at least try it on the InnoTools Downloader. I figured it might have something to do with the Unicode differences as JerryDodge said, when I was trying to figure out things. The VCL load code was similar, but I guess it has to be specifically programmed into the DLL to be able to load it? I know absolutely nothing about DLL and am trying to learn as I go basically.

Comment: Added images for clarification and maybe help someone else who might be having the same question later, but ignore the Download Failure / File Not Found errors, those were on purpose to get a good screenshot of the page/popup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [VCL Styles for Inno setup](https://code.google.com/p/vcl-styles-plugins/wiki/VCLStylesInnoSetup) plugin only can apply the style on these inno controls

- TNewEdit
- TEdit
- TPasswordEdit
- TNewMemo
- TNewComboBox
- TNewListBox
- TListBox
- TNewButton
- TNewCheckBox
- TNewRadioButton
- TSelectFolderForm
- TFolderTreeView
- TStartMenuFolderTreeView
- TRichEditViewer
- TNewStaticText
- TNewNotebook
- TNewNotebookPage
- TPanel

  so you cannot apply a skin to a third-party component like the used by the `InnoTools Downloader` plugin. Anyway you can request such feature in the [issue page](https://code.google.com/p/vcl-styles-plugins/issues/list) of the project.

Comment: So basically, if I don't see any of these specific controls mentioned in either of the downloader scripts, then I have no control over skinning that part of it with VCL. I have an open request on that issue page already, but more than happy to add another one if it's something that only the creator of VCL can do. Is it more a VCL issue, or rather an issue with the downloader implementation and they would have to implement something? I was so happy when I tried Inno Download Plugin, and it did skin that area, but then had a popup window I couldn't read.

Comment: Marked as answer, posted on the Issue Page of VCL Styles and emailed author of InnoTools Downloader for possible assistance in getting this fixed. Thanks to everyone for their input and helping me learn a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

I actually wrote this code that you're using. I wrote it a while back, so I'm barely familiar with it anymore, but the problem is that you're not using the Unicode version of Inno Setup, as I was when I wrote it. It's not always a very simple switch to the Unicode version, you might have to do a lot to your project(s) to adjust. But the `WideString` type is only available in the Unicode version (as it's a unicode type).

Comment: Jerry, that import is wrong (apart from what type of Inno Setup distribution you use). The `DllLoadStyle` function does not exist in the `itdownload.dll` library. And assuming it's from the post you linked, then the OP would need your library. I think it was an attempt to skin components in the ITD library (since you named your function `DllLoadStyle` which somehow attracts to use it for loading a style for something from a DLL). To skin ITD you would need to *crack* those custom written components.

Comment: The source of that DLL is available with the entire package. I'm assuming anyone can use the same downloaded DLL source and modify it the same as I did, which it appears OP already did, could be wrong though.

Comment: The coding that VCL uses is pretty similar, not using WideString and just using String. Is it rather that VCL has LoadVCLStyleA built into it for their command they use to load the VclStylesInno.dll, whereas itdownloaded.dll either doesn't have a command, or I don't know what it is to load it? I haven't modified any source on it, just modified its usage in my scripting.

Answer (score 1):

Update: The author of  Inno Download Plugin by Mitrich Software has released an update. Inno Download Plugin 1.4.1 fixes the issue with the popup and skins the download page without having the gray box. Cheers and thanks for everyone's help.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/inno-download-plugin/DzhRiLYi66c

So far, the email address on the InnoTools Downloader by Sherlock Software website bounced back.

No reply yet from VCL Styles bug report: https://code.google.com/p/vcl-styles-plugins/issues/detail?id=5&can=1